# Jquery validation messages from xml

Tags: jquery, xml, validation, asynchronous, settimeout

I am using Jquery [valdiation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) for validating the form at client side.
I am fetching validation error messages from an xml file.

```js
$("#"+form).validate({
    errorLabelContainer: "#dialogError", //msg_error
    wrapper: "li",
    rules: {
        txtInfringementID: {
            required: true,
            digits: true
        },
        txtLicenceNumber: {
            required: true            
        },
        txtDateOfOffence: {
            date: true,
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        txtInfringementID: {
            required:this.errorMessage("InfringementID","Required"),
            digits: "Inf Id must be numeric only"
        },
        txtDateOfOffence: {
            required: "please enter date of offence",
            date: "Date is not valid"
        },
        txtLicenceNumber:this.errorMessage("LicenceNumber", "Required"),
        txtSurname: this.errorMessage("DebtorSurname", "Required")
    }
)};
```

errorMessage function is below.

```js
this.errorMessage = function (Field, Rule) {

    var message;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../../../ErrorMessages.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {

            $(xml).find("*[Name='" + Field + "']").each(function () {
                message = $(this).find(Rule).text();
            });
        }
    });

    return message; **//I am using a debugger here**
}
```

and the xml I am using is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ErrorMessage>
    <Field Name="InfringementID">
        <Required>Infringement ID is required</Required>
        <Digit>Infringement ID should be numeric only</Digit>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="LicenceNumber">
        <Required>License Number is Mandatory</Required>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="DebtorSurname">
        <Required>Debtor Surname is Mandatory</Required>
    </Field>
</ErrorMessage>
```

But the problem is that when I use debugger, I am getting messages from xml. If I don't use debugger, I am getting default message 'this field is required'. I think, the issue is `this.errorMessage()` is a asynchrounous request and this request is taking some time to complete. I tried to put some delay using **setTimeout function**. but I don't know where to put the time delay. Any thought process is welcomed.

I am setting timeout like this.

```
required:setTimeout(this.errorMessage("InfringementID","Required"),10000),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`errorMessage` starts the ajax-call and returns directly after that without waiting for the response. Because of that `message` will be `null` all the time.
Your approach with `setTimeout` only delays the call of `errorMessage`. The result will be the same as without it.
Make your ajax-call synchronous and thereby wait for the result of it.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,     // wait for the response
    url: "../../../ErrorMessages.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        $(xml).find("*[Name='" + Field + "']").each(function () {
            message = $(this).find(Rule).text();
        });
    }
});
```

---

**Edit**
I don't exactly know what you are asking for, but I will give it a try...
Because of the last line of your question above, perhaps the following part will do it for you

```js
required: function() {
    setTimeout(this.errorMessage("InfringementID", "Required"), 10000);
}
```

Comment: thanks, cannot I put some delay when I am returning the message.